# Why Prelude have same functions with just different args?

Tags: haskell

Consider functions from Prelude like `zipWith`. There are other functions like `zipWith3` ... `zipWith7` which differs only by number of arguments. There are many similar examples, in other languages too (scala, ocaml).

What are reasons for creating functions with particular number of elements? Why not use generalized version? Maybe derive particular `zipWith` from number of applied arguments

Comment: What would be the type of that generalized version?

Comment: @sepp2k something like (a1->a2->...->an->b) -> ([a1->a2->...->an->b]->[b]) -> [b] , but don`t know about actual implementation

Comment: @Sigrlami, you can handwave with `...` on SO, but that doesn't work so well in an actual type system. Variadic functions are pretty horrible in typed languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The generalized version of `zipWith` does exist: it's the [`ZipList` applicative functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList):

```
import Control.Applicative

zipWith  f a1 a2 = getZipList (f <$> ZipList a1 <*> ZipList a2)
zipWith3 f a1 a2 a3 = getZipList (f <$> ZipList a1 <*> ZipList a2 <*> ZipList a3)
```

And so on.  The thing is, it's generally just quicker to use the `zipWithN` functions that to wrap everything with a `ZipList` constructor.

---

**EDIT:** chi's comment points out that I wasn't as clear as I should have been.  The point was that the `ZipList` wrapper allows us to use the applicative `f <$> x1 <*> ... <*> xn` idiom to zip any number of lists whose element types are compatible with `f`'s type.

Comment: This is a nice example, but still follows the pattern I've described initially, I found examples of functions that go on to 26 arguments in xml parsing library. I understand idea of quick-and-ready approach, but it's seems to me strange to use such hadwritten functions. As I understand to create in general n-ary functions we will need dependent types.

Comment: @Sigrlami, the usual saying is that if a function has five arguments, it's probably missing some. I think that's the most I've ever used. Some oddballs in `HList`, `printf`, and of course Okasaki's embedded postscript calculator can use lots, but generally that's code smell.

Comment: @Sigrlami The point of this answer is not to define `zipWith, zipWith2, ...` up to a large number of arguments. Instead, the point is to directly use `getZipList,(<$>),(<*>),ZipList` -- four functions only -- to achieve the same goal. In other words, this is suggesting to avoid defining a variadic function and applying it, instead using a slightly more verbose syntax for applicatives which works for any number of lists.

Comment: @chi: Yeah, I clearly messed this one up.  I've added an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

It is theoretically possible to write a function with variable number of arguments in Haskell, some libraries use this quite well, but nothing is going to beat the clarity and efficiency of having individual functions that the compiler can more easily optimize.  The `zipWithN` functions are easy to use, make sense to beginners and advanced users alike, and do their jobs very well.

If you need an N-way `zipWith` where all the lists have the same type, then just use `Data.List.transpose`:

```
zipWithN :: ([a] -> b) -> [[a]] -> [b]
zipWithN f = map f . transpose
```

If you need the lists to have differing types, you're probably going about it wrong.  Heterogeneous lists are not trivial in Haskell and most other statically typed languages pretty much by definition.

Comment: The lists of different types case can be done easily using the [`ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) applicative.

Answer (score 5):

The primary purpose of generalised functions is that you can use them to write other polymorphic code, without a hassle. That can drastically [reduce code duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

However, that's barely possible with something like a generalised `zipWith`: at least where you use it, you will need to have some *fixed* number of list arguments, otherwise the compiler couldn't be sure the combiner-function also has that right number of arguments. So the only advantage of such a generalised function would be that you only need a single exposed name. And that is rather less beneficial, it would hardly outweigh the disadvantages of the more obscure error messages when you get something wrong, and the occasionally needed explicit local signatures when things get *too* polymorphic.

Comment: This answer would benefit from some examples, e.g. what you mean by "combiner-function"